# How to using eq() while dealing in Div tag - Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I am having this following HTML code,

```
<div class="row add_all">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="pf-title">Title</span>
        <div class="pf-field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Write Something here.." />
            <button class="add-subject" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
            <div style="display: inline-flex; margin-bottom: 22px;">
            <select data-placeholder="Allow In Search" id="input_data1" style="width: 70%; margin-right: 10px;">
            <option value="">Level</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
            <select data-placeholder="Allow In Search" id="input_data2" style="width: 70%; margin-right: 10px;">
            <option value="">Level</option>
            <option value="I">I</option>
            <option value="II">II</option>
            <option value="III">III</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="sodmzs"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I am having one textbox in the first row and two combo boxes in the second row. When the user will click on plus icon, another textbox in the first row and two combo boxes in the second row will get generated and added. User can generate as many as they wants (1 textbox and 2 combo boxes) via clicking on the add icon.
To get the whole values from the generated div tag, I wrote the following code,

```
$("#form_id_name").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var json_data = [];

    $(".add_all").each(function(){
        title = $(this).children().eq(0).find('input').val();
        level_no =  $(this).children().eq(0).find("option:selected").text();
        level_ro =  $(this).children().eq(1).find("option:selected").text();
        var single_data = {"title":title, "level_no":level_no, "level_ro":level_ro}
        json_data.push(single_data);
    });
    var string_data = JSON.stringify(json_data);
    console.log(string_data);

    *ajax code*
```

But this code doesn't help me to get the desired output that I want. Can you help me out to know where I am doing it wrong ?
Thanks.

NOTE: I am appending the HTML code using `$('.sodmzs').append(fieldHTML);` where `fieldHTML` contains html code encapsulated in single quotes.

Comment: You're going to have problems if you're duplicating `<selects>` with the same id.  Well, maybe no problems - but it's certainly invalid HTML - ids must be unique on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using too many methods to access the DOM elements, this code is a simplified version, I tested it in codepen and returns:

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var json_data;

  $(".add_all").each(function () {
    title = $(this).find("input").val();
    level_no = $(this).find("option:selected:first").text();
    level_ro = $(this).find("option:selected:last").text();

    json_data = { 
      title: title, 
      level_no: level_no, 
      level_ro: level_ro 
    };
  });
  json_data = JSON.stringify(json_data);

  console.log(json_data);
});

// "{'title':'my title','level_no':'1','level_ro':'III'}"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have multiple generated divs (by clicking on add button) and I guess you did only for a single div elements.

When using this code I am able to get only the first div elements values even when there are more data.

Expected Output : `[{'title':'my title 1','level_no':'1','level_ro':'III'},{'title':'my title 2','level_no':'1','level_ro':'III'},{'title':'my title 3','level_no':'1','level_ro':'III'}]`

Observed Output : `{'title':'my title','level_no':'1','level_ro':'III'}`
If you can see, I have even used in my code `json_data.push(single_data);`  for adding []

Comment: @sodmzs1 it works fine with multiple entries. I've tested it in this codepen https://codepen.io/jdgomezb/pen/KKZNwVd?editors=1111. Here's the actual console log `[{'title':'one','level_no':'1','level_ro':'I'},{'title':'two','level_no':'2','level_ro':'II'},{'title':'three','level_no':'3','level_ro':'III'}]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pushing `single_data` onto `json_data` before assigning it a value.  Due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), `single_data` gets declared at the top of the function - so it's defined and you won't get an error.  But, you also won't get your data.

Change

```js
json_data.push(single_data);
var single_data = {"title":title, "level_no":level_no, "level_ro":level_ro}
```

to just

```js
json_data.push({"title":title, "level_no":level_no, "level_ro":level_ro});
```

Also, you could clean up the code a bit by adding classes to your inputs & selects.  So this:

```
title = $(this).children().eq(0).find('input').val();
```

could be simplified to this:

```
title = $(this).find(".titleinput").val();
```

It'll also be more robust if you change the underlying markup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

My bad, that was an error that i resolved later too and I forgot to update in code here but yet I am getting only the first div elements values. It simply avoiding all the other generated div elements values.

Comment: It's a little unclear what the markup would look like if someone clicks the `.add-subject` button.